# Найти центральные точки подмассивов в двумерном массиве

Tags: алгоритм, логика, псевдокод

> Массив произвольного размера:
>
> - Помещающий в себя минимум одно здание 4х4
> - заполнен числами которые отображают высоту здания (числа положительные, земля плоская, высота = 0)
>
> Все здания:
>
> - Имеют положительную высоту
> - Имеют прямоугольную форму
> - Плоские наверху
> - Края параллельны системе координат
> - Если ячейки касаются угла другого здания то они относятся к разным зданиям
>
> Надо найти центральные точки зданий чей размер больше или равен 4х4 (3х10 не подходит). Координаты округляются вниз.

Основная трудность - нахождение этих самых зданий с условие что их размер минимум 4х4

П.С. Пытался сделать через кучу циклов, условий и дополнительных переменных и что-то не вышло (алгоритм хромает)

Comment: пример массива бы

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ljseh4 (тут вместо массива ось координат, но думаю будет понятно)

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи

Comment: Основная трудность - нахождение этих самых зданий с условие что их размер минимум 4х4

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/c4oov тут мой код, input и правильный output

Comment: не надо ссылок, весь необходимый для вопроса код вставляйте в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Скачал ваш файл с данными и подготовил его для решения на `php`:

```
$ar = file(__DIR__. '/level4_0.in');
$ar = array_map('trim', $ar);
array_splice($ar, 41, 1);
array_splice($ar, 0, 1);
$ar = array_map(function($row){
    $row = explode(' ', $row);
    $row = array_map('intval', $row);
    return $row;
}, $ar);
```

Получил двумерный массив вида:

```
[
    [0, 5, 5, ..],
    [0, 5, 5, ..],
    ..
]
```

Решение в итоге такое:

Перебираем строки. В каждой строке перебираем столбцы. Получаем клетку поля. Если она НЕпустая и над ней пусто (либо это первая строка), то понимаем, что нашли верхний левый угол здания. С этого места ещё двумя вложенными циклами измеряем сначала ширину здания, а затем (если ширина подходящая) и длину. Подходящее здание запоминаем. В любом случае (подошло здание или нет), продолжаем поиск следующего здания в той же строке, но с того места где закончили искать первое.

```
$found = [];
for ($row = 0; $row < count($ar); $row++) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < count($ar[$row]); $col++) {
        if ($ar[$row][$col] && (!$row || !$ar[$row - 1][$col])) {
            for ($c = $col; $c < count($ar[$row]); $c++) {
                if (!$ar[$row][$c]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (($c - $col) > 2) {
                for ($r = $row; $r < count($ar); $r++) {
                    if (!$ar[$r][$col]) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (($r - $row) > 2) {
                    $found[] = [
                        "row" => floor(($row + $r) / 2),
                        "col" => floor(($col + $c) / 2),
                    ];
                }
            }
            $col = $c;
        }
    }
}
echo "found:\n";
foreach ($found as $node) {
    echo "{$node['row']}x{$node['col']}\n";
}
```

Результат (вручную не проверял):

```
found:
12x32
22x52
32x22
32x42
51x22
51x57
61x42
71x62
81x47
```

Также не проверял валидность входных данных: "прямоугольность" зданий, отсутствие пересечений зданий или дыр внутри здания.